# Oracle ranking with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to rank my results based on a custom condition. Let us assume that my data looks like the following:

```
col1   col2    col3     
-----------------------
1       1       2       
1       3       33   
2       4       5   
3       6       40  
1       2       5
3       5       10
```

I now want to group by col1 and order by col2 and then rank the results. However, I only want to increase the rank if col3 is larger than 30. So the results should look like:

```
col1   col2    col3    rank     
-----------------------------
1       1       2       1   
1       2       5       1
1       3       33      2  
2       4       5       1 
3       5       10      1 
3       6       40      2
```

I just can't find an elegant solution to the problem. If I just use classic ranking, the whole thing does not work of course; e.g.:

`RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2)`

If possible, I would like to work with window functions here due to performance issues. I also work in Google's Bigquery environment.

Comment: In your sample data, col2 and col3 are monotonically increasing for each value of col1. Is this typical? If not, you should edit your question and include more representative data. –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this appears to work.  Rather than doing a `rank`, I'm doing a cumulative sum of the number of rows that have a `col3` value greater than 30.

```
with x as (
    select 1 col1, 1 col2, 2 col3 from dual union all
    select 1, 3, 33 from dual union all
    select 2, 4, 5 from dual union all
    select 3, 6, 40 from dual union all
    select 1, 2, 5 from dual union all
    select 3, 5, 10 from dual
 )
 select col1, col2, col3,
        sum( case when col3 > 30 then 1 else 0 end ) 
          over( partition by col1
                order by col2 ) + 1 rnk
   from x
```

The [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6498) for this is available as well.

Comment: Brilliant, that should do the job.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about using conditional logic?  This may do what you want:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1
             ORDER BY (CASE WHEN col3 < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 30 END)
            )
```

Comment: I have to order by col2 as well though, and col2 has distinct values. Oh and something I forgot to mention, I want to use it in Google's BigQuery which does not allow functions inside window functions.